# V.Digit Grass Error

Tags: grass-gis

I am trying to slowly switch from ArcGIS to GRASS but the interactive V.Digit tool is giving me a headache. I am trying to add supervised classifications training samples (i.e. polygons) for use in a maximum likelihood classification but when I type,

```
v.digit -n map=Tsample bgcmd='d.rast map=landsat@image'
```

I receive the error...

```
 'Option <map> does not accept multiple answers'
```

Removing the bgcmd shows me that this error is association with the bgcmd not the first map declaration. I assume that this error has something to do with my procedure as im rather new to GRASS  than a bug...

I am executing the function via the command console in the GRASS 6.4.3svn GUI.

Comment: Which GRASS GIS version do you use?

Comment: GRASS 6.4.3svn GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are, calling the digitizer like this, using the old Tcl/TK based digitizer. See http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Digitizing_tool for screenshots of old versus new digitizer.

Please use the new digitizer which you enable in the display manager, right side: change "2D view" -> "Digitizer" in the selector.

Comment: Ah perfect... I originally used v.digit as recommended on the GRASS wiki page http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_classification

Comment: I have updated the wiki page.